# Class 'Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMapsProvider' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to run some legacy application but I hit a wall with a geocoder dependency.

I get the message: `Fatal error: Class Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMapsProvider' not found`.

My source code shows the error at the marked line:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Geocoder\Provider;

use Geocoder\Exception\NoResultException;
use Geocoder\Exception\QuotaExceededException;
use Geocoder\Exception\UnsupportedException;
use Geocoder\Exception\InvalidCredentialsException;
use Geocoder\HttpAdapter\HttpAdapterInterface;
use Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMapsProvider as ExtendGoogleMapsProvider;

class GoogleMapsProvider extends ExtendGoogleMapsProvider
{ <===== The error line is HERE
```

I installed the `willdurand/geocoder` dependency:

```
  "require" : {
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module" : "0.7.0",
    "php" : ">=5.3.3",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions" : "2.3.8",
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize" : "1.4.0",
    "doctrine/common" : "2.3.0",
    "twbs/bootstrap" : "2.3.2",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user" : "0.1.x-dev",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm" : "master-dev",
    "mwillbanks/zfc-twitter-bootstrap" : "master-dev",
    "zendframework/zendframework" : "2.2.5",
        "willdurand/geocoder": "^3.3",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^4.0"
  },
```

And a `diagnose` command says:

```
$ php composer.phar diagnose
Checking composer.json: FAIL
name : invalid value (Extrapack), must match [A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_.-]*/[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_.-]*
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
require.gedmo/doctrine-extensions : exact version constraints (2.3.8) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize : exact version constraints (1.4.0) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.doctrine/common : exact version constraints (2.3.0) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.twbs/bootstrap : exact version constraints (2.3.2) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm : unbound version constraints (master-dev) should be avoided
require.mwillbanks/zfc-twitter-bootstrap : unbound version constraints (master-dev) should be avoided
require.zendframework/zendframework : exact version constraints (2.2.5) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

My `phar` module:

```
Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.2
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Id: 780be432570e80dd34c1a9c217ef87ade22bf136 $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives enabled
ZIP-based phar archives enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   enabled
Native OpenSSL support  enabled
```

Onr thing that puzzles me in the source code, is the use of

```
use Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMapsProvider as ExtendGoogleMapsProvider;
```

which indicates the class extends itself. This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [source](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/tree/v3.3.0/src/Geocoder/Provider), the class `Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMapsProvider` does not exist.

This may indicate that you are using a newer version than the legacy project used to.

Looking at the [changelog](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-alpha1-2014-12-18) confirms that the `Provider` suffix has been removed in the `3.x` line.

For a start, you probably want to use an older version. Run

```
$ composer require willdurand/geocoder:^2.8.2
```

Alternatively, try using the renamed provider without the suffix on the `3.x` line:

```
use Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMaps;

class GoogleMapsProvider extends GoogleMaps
{
    // ...
}
```

**Note** The class name is aliased using

```
use Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMapsProvider as ExtendGoogleMapsProvider;
```

to prevent collisions.

For reference, see:

- https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/tree/v3.3.0/src/Geocoder/Provider
- https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-alpha1-2014-12-18
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Spot on! So I'll reverse and use the legacy dependencies that make use of the correct classes.

Comment: I decided to try your alternatives solutions. I renamed the `ExtendGoogleMapsProvider` class into a `GoogleMaps` class but this did not help. Then I downgraded the dependency to `willdurand/geocoder:^2.8.2` and that proved to work just fine. So this is the solution I will go for.